# Python - Subtract a number from a list at a specific position

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples and an array of integers. I'm trying to subtract a specific element from the array according to the given tuple. The 1st element of the tuple represents the index at which the number is to be subtracted from the array and the 2nd element represents the actual number to be subtracted. I've tried the following approach, but the index is going out of bounds:

```
li = [(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
array = [1,2,3] 
for idx,i in enumerate(li):
    print(array)
    array[idx] = array[idx] - li[idx][1]
array
```

Output is :

```
[1, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 1]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-603d874cf0cc> in <module>
      3 for idx,i in enumerate(li):
      4     print(array)
----> 5     array[idx] = array[idx] - li[idx][1]
      6 array

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Expected output is that after every iteration, the elements should be subtracted from the array and it should eventually be [0, 0, 0]. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `enumerate` since each tuple already contains the index as the first element.

```
li = [(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
array = [1,2,3] 
for idx, sub in li:
    print(array)
    array[idx] -= sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention one thing in the question explicitly, that is I want my final answer to be either 0 or positive. But that I've easily resolved using if condition. Thanks again for identifying my mistake!

Comment: @Parth09P You can use `array[idx] = max(0, array[idx] - sub)` for that.

Comment: @Parth09P, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)